# Post preview:blob instead of type when using Redux Form with File Input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, react-redux, redux-form

I have an error when uploading a file using Redux Forn with File Input, this is what it is looks when the file is sent to the backend API. Note that the "preview" sends a "blob", thus the upload file can't be received by the backend API

```
{"PROJECT_ID":"6237581","SUBJECT":"test nilai UN","MESSAGE":"test nilai UN","file_upload":
[{"preview":"blob:http://localhost:8089/18dc2302-02a3-475a-9d08-e1a6ac8aabf1"}]}:
```

[The preview of file that is sent.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWLPy.png)
This is my component

```
export class ReduxFileInput extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <FileInput
        name={this.props.name}
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
        accept=".zip,.doc,.docs,.docx,.xls,.pdf,.xlsx,.jpg,.jpeg,.png"
        onDrop={(event)=> this.props.input.onDrop(event.target.files[0])}
        {...this.props.custom}
        >
      </FileInput>
    )
  }
}
```

And this is my redux form

```
               <Field
                  inputName="EVIDENCE"
                  name="file_upload"
                  type='file'
                  component = {ReduxFileInput}                  
                />
```

Comment: Are you using webpack , have you config and install file loader
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader

Comment: Yes im using webpack, and i have downloaded file loader, but havent used it for this particular problem, how do i actaully config this please? Thank you very much!!

Comment: For config, you may go to the link that mentioned above comment. in usage section of link , just copy that code and paste in you webpack.config file .

That is the rule

Comment: This is what i did `rules:[
          {
            test: /\.(zip|doc|docs|docx|xls|pdf|xlsx|jpg|jpeg|png)$/,
            use:[
              {
                loader: 'file-loader',
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
    },` , but if i do that, this error will show 
Module parse failed: /Users/rizasatyabudhi/Documents/Web Development/Projects/PRouDS/sigma_node/src/components/app.jsxUnexpected token (84:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| // import Store from '/Store.jsx'

Comment: try https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-loader

Comment: both can be config.


module: {
  loaders: [
    { test: /\.(woff|png)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000' },
    { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: 'file-loader'}
  ]
},

Comment: It still shown the same error as before, this always occur when i add new config to the webpack
Module parse failed: /Users/rizasatyabudhi/Documents/Web Development/Projects/PRouDS/sigma_node/src/components/app.jsxUnexpected token (84:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Comment: show the webpack.config file

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rizasatyabudhi/fda029350b83a6546db3baedfa6345e4 Here is my webpack.config gile

Comment: What type of file are you uploading? try png file

Comment: .zip,.doc,.docs,.docx,.xls,.pdf,.xlsx,.jpg,.jpeg,.png these are the accepted file. So the user can upload those type of file

Comment: Have you try png. in your config file file-loader mentioned two times, and you didn't mentioned url-loader in the config file.